# What are the limitations of vector_integrate?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve this problem in sympy 1.7 using [vector_integrate](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/api/vectorfunctions.html#vector-integrate):

[image]

I thought this would work:

```
import sympy
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, ParametricRegion, vector_integrate
from sympy.abc import t,x,y

C = CoordSys3D('C')

region = ParametricRegion((t, t), (t, 0, 1))

field = x * C.i + (x+y) * C.j

vector_integrate(field, region)
```

But the result is:

```
2*x + y
```

Did I wrongly translate the problem into sympy or is this a type problem not supported by `vector_integrate` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the coordinates from the given coordinate system e.g. `C.x` and not some other symbol called `x`.

```
In [15]: from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, ParametricRegion, vector_integrate 
    ...: C = CoordSys3D('C')                                                                                                      

In [16]: region = ParametricRegion((t, t), (t, 0, 1))                                                                             

In [17]: field = C.x * C.i + (C.x+C.y) * C.j   # note C.x  rather than  x                                                         

In [18]: vector_integrate(field, region)                                                                                          
Out[18]: 3/2
```

Any other symbol is treated as being a scalar constant in the field. Perhaps it's easier to understand if we change the names of the symbols:

```
In [19]: from sympy.abc import a, b                                                                                               

In [20]: field = a * C.i + (a+b) * C.j                                                                                            

In [21]: vector_integrate(field, region)                                                                                          
Out[21]: 2⋅a + b
```